# Join arrays using function to create all combinations

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have one array:

```
Aaa
Bbb
```

Another array:

```
Ddd
Fff
```

How do I use one function to join the 2 arrays?

```
AaaDdd
AaaFff
BbbDdd
BbbFff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)); COUNTA(B1:B)); CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9); COUNTA(A1:A))); CHAR(9)))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @VyacheslavSVXCompany fixed, try now

Comment: Thanks, that's OK

Comment: Wow, the witchcraft of one cell that does it all. Nice

Comment: Need help. CONCATENATE 50000 limit string. How can this formula be implemented differently?